# Computation of Ricci Tensor for Product Metric on Total Space of Vector Bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to compute the Ricci tensor of a metric on the total space of a vector bundle which is given in an orthonormal coframe. In terms of this frame the metric looks like a warped product.

\begin{equation}
g = f^2 \eta_{i} \otimes \eta_{i} + g^2 g_{B}
\end{equation}

Here f and g are constants and $g_{B}$ is the metric on the base of the bundle. Technically a warped product metric is set on a product manifold whereas the space I am dealing with is a vector bundle. Given however that a vector bundle is locally trivial and the computing the metric is done pointwise is it valid to use the equations for warped product metrics to get the Ricci tensor of this metric?

Comment: Using $f$ and $g$ for constants would be horrible enough, but $g$ is also the metric tensor a few times.

Comment: Hint: What does the metric $g$ look like in a local trivialization induced by the coframe $\eta_i$?